# UITableViewController/UITableView Not Pull Down

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I got a UITableView in a storyboard for a Universal application, I want to prevent it from being pulled down since there is no refresh logic link to it so it mustn't have the pull down behaviour at all.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide some code of what you have tried, if you haven't tried anything go away have a try even if it is a google search then come back later if you still can't do it and provide us with some code that you have tried. Also read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any refresh logic, don't add a `UIRefreshController` to your table.

If you've some other reason to want to prevent the table view from scrolling, set `scrollEnabled` to `NO`.  If you just want to stop the table view from scrolling past its bounds, set `bounces` to `NO`.

Comment: I don't have this assigned but you can still drag the UITableView